Expo React Native cannot send a request
I am working on a React Native app with the Expo framework. I was able to create a development client and installed it on my iOS device. The app seems to work, at least I can open the app and visit the login flow.
However, I when I try to log in, it fails as:
 LOG  Sending request to: http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/verify_user.json
 ERROR  Network request failed: [TypeError: Network request failed]

Here are things I know:

No issue on the endpoint.

> curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/verify_user.json" -d '{"user":{"email":"john@example.com","is_verified":true}}'
{"success":true}%


Login works on the web part without any issues.

However, when it comes to iOS app, things start to break. Here is the function responsible for the mobile log in on ContinueWithEmail.tsx:
  const verifyUserEmail = async (email: string) => {
    const authEndpoint = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/verify_user.json';

    try {
      console.log('Sending request to:', authEndpoint);
      const response = await fetch(authEndpoint, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: '{"user":{"email":"john@example.com","is_verified":true}}',
      });

      console.log('Response status:', response.status);
      const responseData = await response.json();
      console.log('Response data:', responseData);

      if (response.ok) {
        if (email && me && Platform.OS !== 'web')
          if (email !== me.email) {
            AsyncStorage.setItem('special_offer', '');
            clearCache && clearCache();
          }
        if (!(!!errors.email && !isValid)) {
          navigation.navigate('continue-with-email-password');
        }
      } else if (responseData.auth_provider) {
        if (Platform.OS === 'web') {
          setShowProviderModal(true);
          setErrorName(responseData.error);
        }
        Alert.alert(
          m('onBoarding.error.title'),
          responseData?.error,
          [
            {
              text: m('onBoarding.error.errorMsg', {
                provider: responseData.auth_provider,
              }),
              onPress: () => loginPress(),
            },
            {
              text: 'Dismiss',
              onPress: () => {},
            },
          ],
          {
            cancelable: true,
          }
        );
      } else if (responseData.error) {
        setErrors({ email: responseData?.error });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Network request failed:', error);
      Alert.alert(
        'Network Error',
        'There was a problem connecting to the server. Please check your internet connection and try again.'
      );
    }
  };

As I am not a mobile developer, I am pretty much clueless on how to debug this. Any pointers would be highly appreciated!

Have you tried replacing 127.0.0.1 with your local ip address

@PhantomSpooks, I have tried 192.168.1.110:8081, 192.168.1.110:5000 and 192.168.1.110. In these cases, it still does not hit my API at all, but the error message has become [SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected character: <].

There are a few things you should check:

Check the API URL: If your app is not communicating with your API, verify the URL you’re using. For example, if your API is running on your PC and your app is running on your phone, you cannot use 'localhost.' Instead, you must use the IP address where the API is hosted.

Allow HTTP Requests: Your app might be blocking HTTP requests. To allow HTTP requests (instead of HTTPS) in Expo, you’ll need to modify some properties in your app.json file.


Here's an example of how to enable HTTP requests on iOS devices:
app.json
ios: {
    buildNumber: "",
    bundleIdentifier: "",
    infoPlist: {
      NSAppTransportSecurity: { NSAllowsArbitraryLoads: true } // Enable HTTP requests
    },
}

And here's an example for Android in app.json:
[
  'expo-build-properties',
  {
    android: {
      usesCleartextTraffic: true // Enable HTTP requests
    },
    ios: {
      flipper: true
    }
  }
]

Notice that I'm using expo-build-properties to edit the native code during the prebuild. To enable usesCleartextTraffic, you would typically edit the Android manifest directly.

I've previously answered a related question, and here are some helpful links:

How to enable HTTP requests using Expo
Expo Documentation - Build Properties
Android Developer Docs - Cleartext Traffic


I agree with Pedro here and add a plus 1 for most likely the http requests being blocked.

@DustinForsyth, the problem is definitely HTTP requests being blocked, but I have no idea hot wo unblock, ATM.

@pedro-bueno, I have tried your first suggestion by replacing 127.0.0.1 with 192.168.1.110 but it did not work either. Also, your second suggestion was in place already.
